# Rails Email Parsing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email-parsing

I want to have the ability in my rails application to receive incoming emails and parse them in a particular way.

**incoming_controller.rb**

```
class IncomingController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:create]
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:create]
  def create
    # Find the user
     user = User.find_by(email: params[:sender])

     # Find the topic
     topic = Topic.find_by(title: params[:subject])

     # Assign the url to a variable after retreiving it from
     url = params["body-plain"]

     # If the user is nil, create and save a new user
     if user.nil?
       user = User.new(email: params[:sender], password: "password")
       user.save!
     end

     # If the topic is nil, create and save a new topic
      if topic.nil?
        topic = Topic.new(title: params[:subject], user: user)

        topic.save!
      end

      bookmark = topic.bookmarks.build(user: user, url: url, description: "bookmark for #{url}")

      bookmark.save!

    # Assuming all went well.
    head 200
  end
end
```

Using this controller I can only extract 3 values = user :sender, topic :subject and url "body-plain".

How can I add a 4th value in the email to parse a :description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `params[:description]` implementation should theoretically work the same as the other `params` items used in your method, you just need to make sure that that whatever calls your `IncomingController#create` action is sending a `:description` param.

Or, if you cannot add parameters to whatever is calling the controller action, maybe you could add it to the `params['body-plain']` that you're currently using for the `url`? You could store multiple fields in the email body by using a serialized text format, for example (using YAML):

```
url: http://example.com
description: I'm a description
```

Then in your controller, you'd parse that field like this:

```
class IncomingController < ApplicationController
  require 'yaml'
  def create
    # ...
    body_params = YAML.load(params['body-plain'])
    url = body_params[:url]
    description = body_params[:description]
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: How would I set the text in the email so that it would be recognized as the description? For example I set the subject of the email to equal the topic. What could I set from the email to equal the description?

Comment: That depends on what is calling your controller...I assume you have some sort of email receiving setup which is parsing the emails into a hash and submitting to your controller action? If you can control that, you can add the param to the hash. If you can't do that, you can add it in the email body like I explained in my edited answer.

Comment: I am trying the method you outlined in the answer but url and description is not getting picked by the params. It reads them both as nil.

Comment: When I test the basic behavior in a test app on my end, it works. Are you storing the YAML.load result to your own variable (like `body_params` in my example), and then accessing url and description like `body_params[:url]`? And only using `params` for the other fields? Without seeing the entire controller as you tried it, it is difficult to say what isn't working.